# How to auto refresh previous page from popup form submission

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to reload the previous page from where I opened a popup (a php file) with window.open function. I was able to close the popup with self.close() function, but previous page from where I opened the popup is not auto refreshing.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    location.replace(document.referrer);
    self.close();
</script>
```

Comment: Did that answer work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the bellow code snippet to reload the main page on closing the pop up page.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Popup Page</button>


<script>
// -----POP SECTION-------
function myFunction() {
  window.open("http://localhost/popup_page.");
}
// -----END POP SECTION-------

// -------REFRESH PAGE ON POPUP CLOSE-----
var blurred = false;
window.onblur = function() { blurred = true; };
window.onfocus = function() { blurred && (location.reload()); };
// -------END REFRESH PAGE ON POPUP CLOSE-----
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `window.opener`. should work while it's not cross domain

```
window.opener.document.location.reload()
```